# Knockout checkbox binding

Tags: knockout.js

Refer to this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/zvCeN/5/). 
I am planning to create a Contact Table where got 3 mode "New", "Edit" and "View" in order to control user input. 
Everything work fine except the checkbox where the checked or unchecked display is not refresh after click. Somehow it remain the origin value until it blur.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the following line:

```
<td width="*%" data-bind="click: function() { $data.Editing('DisplayName'); }">
```

When you click on check box the click event of TD element is occurred instead of click oo checkbox element.

If you change click event to double click it will work:

```
<td data-bind="event: {dblclick: function() { $data.Editing('IsOrganization'); }}">
```